# How can I have my mobile view in a container-fluid and the desktop site in a container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I'm building a website using laravel and bootstrap 3. When I apply a .container class the site displays well on  medium and large screen sizes but too small on smaller devices like phones (with huge padding on both sides). And when I apply the .container-flud class, it displays well in smaller devices and covers the whole screen in large devices (which I don't want).

So what I want is to have the mobile view in container-fluid and medium and large screen view in a container. Is this possible? and how can I achieve this?

I'm using bootstrap 3

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You can alternate .container and .container-fluid on window resize.

Comment: @Chayan No no ! People will never resize windows while using mobile devices !

Answer (score 1):

You may use `.container` and put the following overwrite media query :

```
@media (max-width: 415px){
 .container{
   min-width:100% !important;
   max-width:100% !important;
 }
}
```

Comment: these are my codes. where do I put the codes you suggested?

Comment: I added it but nothing has changed

Comment: Don't forget to compile assets after modifying the file .